# PowerShell advanced parameter validation on nested workflows

Tags: validation, powershell, parameters, workflow

We would like to use advanced parameter validation inside nested powershell workflows.
Normaly that doesn't work.

```
workflow child
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.String]$Identity,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.String]$Server,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
    )
}

workflow parent
{
    child -Identity 'Test' -Server $null
}

parent

At line:17 char:5
+     child -Identity 'Test' -Server $null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Advanced parameter validation is not supported on nested workflows.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterValidationNotSupportedOnNestedWorkflows
```

Is there an other way like in this [post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/orchestrator/2012/04/26/implementing-your-own-runbook-input-parameter-validation-checking/) to validate the parameters?

I tried it like this but there is first of all a problem to resolve the `$using:` inside a scriptblock and i don't find a way to get all input parameters like `$PSBoundParameters` in a normal script.

```
workflow parent
{
    child -Identity 'Test' -Server $null
}

workflow child
{
    param
    (
        [System.String]$Identity,
        [System.String]$Server,
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
    )

    #Validate input parameters
    InlineScript
    {
        [System.String]$Command = 'Validate-InputParameters'
        function Validate-InputParameters
        {
            param
            (
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
                [System.String]$Identity,
                [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
                [System.String]$Server,
                [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
                [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
            )

            Write-Host -Object 'Successfully validated!'
        }

        if ($using:Identity -ne $null)
        {
            $Command += ' -Identity $using:Identity'
        }

        if ($using:Server -ne $null)
        {
            $Command += ' -Server $using:Server'
        }

        if ($using:Credential -ne $null)
        {
            $Command += ' -Credential'
        }
        $Command
        $ScriptBlock = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create($Command)
        $ScriptBlock.Invoke()
    }
}

parent
Validate-InputParameters -Identity $using:Identity
Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A 
Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script 
workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script 
block is invoked on a remote computer."
At child:16 char:16
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

Comment: It could help you : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574123(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you mean that? I don't see a / the connection to my asked question.

Comment: I just made a comment to share with you a link about the way of _Using Parameters and Variables in Nested Functions and Workflows_, not an answer to solve the problem :)
However `$using:` cannot be used outside the InlineScript and what about `Validate-InputParameters`? Where do you use it?

Comment: `Validate-InputParameters` is inside a `InlineScript`. The variable `$Identity`is therefore empty. So I have to use `$using:`.

Comment: I see it, sorry, it's in the workflow `child`

Comment: You try to use workflow the wrong way. As the message says, `$using:` **must** be used inside the `InLineScript` so you can't use it outside. Plus I'm pretty sure you can't call functions in a workflow from outside of the workflow.

Comment: As I understand is the `$using` inside the `InLineScript` and the function is inside the worfkflow...

Comment: Why you want to use a function inside a workflow to check parameters from outside this workflow? The message is clear `Advanced parameter validation is not supported on nested workflows.` so check your parameters simplier by adding code validation in the workflow but not in a function. For example : `if(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Identity))){}`